# Last week sales not showing correctly

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to calculate last week's sales and I am not sure what is the problem with my DAX query.

DAX Query to calculate this week's sales ( 'DataModel - Sales'[Open Order - Back] ):

```
CALCULATE(SUM('DataModel - Sales'[[Sales Order Line]] Sales]),
          'DataModel - Sales'[[Open Order]] Open Order Type] = "Back"
)
```

DAX Query to calculate last week's sales:

```
VAR
DateSelected = SELECTEDVALUE('DataModel - Sales'[[Open Order]] Snapshot Date]) - 7

RETURN
    CALCULATE(  'DataModel - Sales'[Open Order - Back],
                REMOVEFILTERS('DataModel - Sales'[[Open Order]] Snapshot Date]),
                'DataModel - Sales'[[Open Order]] Snapshot Date] = DateSelected
    )
```

All seems to work fine if I have "Select All" set in the slicer however as soon as I remove one or more value from the slicer the result change and it's incorrect.

I am listing all the date for illustration and debugging purposes and the finishing product should be just a single line with no date. The data is a single flat table structure Power BI dataset so no star schema in the modelling.

[Screenshot of my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAjjo.png)

I've also tried this too:

```
VAR
DateSelected = SELECTEDVALUE('DataModel - Sales'[[Open Order]] Snapshot Date]) - 7
RETURN

CALCULATE(  'DataModel - Sales'[Open Order - Back],
            FILTER( ALL('DataModel - Sales'[[Open Order]] Snapshot Date]),
                    'DataModel - Sales'[[Open Order]] Snapshot Date] = DateSelected
            )
)
```

But still no luck and am pretty sure both approach is doing the same thing.

Comment: Just to be sure about the "DateSelected" used in the measures, create a measure with the following formula ```LW Date = SELECTEDVALUE('DataModel - Sales'[[Open Order]] Snapshot Date]) - 7``` and up it in the table to check if the dates are  always correct

Comment: It's correct that the value is always shown the slicer selected value